# In nifi flow using custom processor pass multiple file in sucess relationship?

Tags: apache-nifi

How to develope  custom apache nifi processor that take one workbook with multiple sheet as a input and number of row in each sheet generate json for each row and pass each generated json file into success relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you use `processSession.clone()` to create child flowfiles from the original (linked via provenance data) and pass them to the `SUCCESS` relationship using `processSession.transfer()`. You can see a good example of this in [`SplitText`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/SplitText.java#L258-L262).